# Trigger working only after alert inside document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            active_menu('mn_tours');
            $('#buscar').val(localStorage.getItem("busqueda"));
            $('#btbuscar').trigger('click');
        });
```

I want to trigger the submit event on that button right away when page loads, but it doesn't seem to work, but when I put this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            active_menu('mn_tours');
            $('#buscar').val(localStorage.getItem("busqueda"));
            alert('Something');
            $('#btbuscar').trigger('click');
        });
```

It actually works, but I don't know how to correct this.

Comment: What is `active_menu`? Is it an asynchronous function?

Comment: @MikeC Yes, that's an async function, but that's not the real problem :/

Comment: Does it setup the click events on `#btbuscar`? Because it sounds like the submit events and stuff aren't setup yet. Having an `alert` allows async functions to complete.

Comment: @MikeC The only thing the function `active_menu` does is to set the "active" class to a link.

Comment: Please post the HTML you are using and the active_menu function. That would really help.

Comment: @AaronFranco The complete html is very extense, but I will post the main one:

`<form id="search_tour" name="search_tour">
        
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" id="buscar" name="buscar">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="btbuscar" style="margin-left:0;">
                    <i class="icon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
    
    </form>`

the active_menu function is:

`function active_menu(opcion){
  $("#"+opcion).addClass('active');

}`

Answer (score 0):

With preliminary testing, this code works...

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="buscar"/>
</form>
<div id="btbuscar">
  help
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#buscar').val(localStorage.getItem("busqueda"));
  $("#btbuscar").bind('click', function(evt){
    $("#myForm").submit()
  })
  $("#myForm").bind('submit', function(evt){
    alert("form submitted")
  })
  $('#btbuscar').trigger('click');
});
```

without seeing your original button listener assignments, I can't tell if this is exactly what you want, but provided the listeners are set properly, this method will work.

Comment: I don't want the alert to be displayed, I want the click event to trigger inside de document ready function so it fires the submit event to do a search. I posted the alert function because it was the only way the trigger worked, but I don't want the alert to be shown.

Comment: Never mind, it works sometimes with `$("#search_tour").submit();` inside dom ready, this is the form:

<form id="search_tour" name="search_tour">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" id="buscar" name="buscar">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="btbuscar" style="margin-left:0;">
                    <i class="icon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>


I want to submit the form as soon the page is loaded.

Comment: This is was my answer accomplished

Answer (score -1):

You have a timming problem. When javascript run this:

```
$('#btbuscar').trigger('click');
```

the HTML element doesnt exist yet, so the submit never happen.

Alert will pause the javascript execution. So when you click OK, the HTML element **#btbuscar** is already loaded on page and the submit work.

It's not safe, but you can use setTimeout

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    active_menu('mn_tours'); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#buscar').val(localStorage.getItem("busqueda"));
        $('#btbuscar').trigger('click');
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: Another solution to trigger either click on button or submit on form when page loads?